# Why is the usage of inversion incorrect? While It seems it should be right

Tags: inversion

The sentence is as below:

> I wish I had ***never*** worked there.

And the sentence with inversion is as below:

> I wish ***never*** had I worked there.

Comment: You may find the following useful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307715/where-to-position-never-in-a-sentence

Comment: @RonaldSole Thanks for your attention. I just want to exercise inversion in "I wish ..." structure. And it is not important to me whether I use never, only, solely, barely, in no way, etc. Could you give me an example with "I wish" in which you used an inversion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an inversion but you cannot place the adverb (never) ahead of the verb (had worked) in that way. You might begin a sentence with **never** (but not after a main clause such as **I wish**). **Never had I worked so hard.**

Comment: @RonaldSole do you mean that I just can use inversion for the main clause? If so, do you think it can be correct "Under no circumstances did I wish you had had an accident"?

Comment: **did I wish** doesn't work. It's a hypothetical statement. You need to change the construction to something like:  **Under no circumstances would I have wished you to have (had) an accident.**

Comment: @RonaldSole SUPERB, so many thanks. I aspired to have sth like that. According to what has gone, we couldn't exercise inversion, here, because of the  hypothetical statement, am I right?